# PHP phpass convert into C# script

Tags: c#, password-encryption, phpass

I have a website to which authentication is done through the following script and generates a password that starts with $P$B...

```
public static function hashPassword($plainPassword)
{
    // use openwall.com phpass class
    $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
    return $hasher->HashPassword($plainPassword);
}


public static function checkPassword($plainPassword, $hashedPassword)
{
    // try with md5
    if (md5($plainPassword) == $hashedPassword) return true;
    // using openwall.com phpass class
    $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
    return $hasher->CheckPassword( $plainPassword, $hashedPassword );
}
```

**Use this class:**

```
class PasswordHash {
var $itoa64;
var $iteration_count_log2;
var $portable_hashes;
var $random_state;

function PasswordHash($iteration_count_log2, $portable_hashes)
{
    $this->itoa64 = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

    if ($iteration_count_log2 < 4 || $iteration_count_log2 > 31)
        $iteration_count_log2 = 8;
    $this->iteration_count_log2 = $iteration_count_log2;

    $this->portable_hashes = $portable_hashes;

    $this->random_state = microtime() . uniqid(rand(), TRUE); // removed getmypid() for compatibility reasons
}

function get_random_bytes($count)
{
    $output = '';
    if ( @is_readable('/dev/urandom') &&
        ($fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb'))) {
        $output = fread($fh, $count);
        fclose($fh);
    }

    if (strlen($output) < $count) {
        $output = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16) {
            $this->random_state =
                md5(microtime() . $this->random_state);
            $output .=
                pack('H*', md5($this->random_state));
        }
        $output = substr($output, 0, $count);
    }

    return $output;
}

function encode64($input, $count)
{
    $output = '';
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $value = ord($input[$i++]);
        $output .= $this->itoa64[$value & 0x3f];
        if ($i < $count)
            $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 8;
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 6) & 0x3f];
        if ($i++ >= $count)
            break;
        if ($i < $count)
            $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 16;
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 12) & 0x3f];
        if ($i++ >= $count)
            break;
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 18) & 0x3f];
    } while ($i < $count);

    return $output;
}

function gensalt_private($input)
{
    $output = '$P$';
    $output .= $this->itoa64[min($this->iteration_count_log2 +
        ((PHP_VERSION >= '5') ? 5 : 3), 30)];
    $output .= $this->encode64($input, 6);

    return $output;
}

function crypt_private($password, $setting)
{
    $output = '*0';
    if (substr($setting, 0, 2) == $output)
        $output = '*1';

    $id = substr($setting, 0, 3);
    # We use "$P$", phpBB3 uses "$H$" for the same thing
    if ($id != '$P$' && $id != '$H$')
        return $output;

    $count_log2 = strpos($this->itoa64, $setting[3]);
    if ($count_log2 < 7 || $count_log2 > 30)
        return $output;

    $count = 1 << $count_log2;

    $salt = substr($setting, 4, 8);
    if (strlen($salt) != 8)
        return $output;

    # We're kind of forced to use MD5 here since it's the only
    # cryptographic primitive available in all versions of PHP
    # currently in use.  To implement our own low-level crypto
    # in PHP would result in much worse performance and
    # consequently in lower iteration counts and hashes that are
    # quicker to crack (by non-PHP code).
    if (PHP_VERSION >= '5') {
        $hash = md5($salt . $password, TRUE);
        do {
            $hash = md5($hash . $password, TRUE);
        } while (--$count);
    } else {
        $hash = pack('H*', md5($salt . $password));
        do {
            $hash = pack('H*', md5($hash . $password));
        } while (--$count);
    }

    $output = substr($setting, 0, 12);
    $output .= $this->encode64($hash, 16);

    return $output;
}

function gensalt_extended($input)
{
    $count_log2 = min($this->iteration_count_log2 + 8, 24);
    # This should be odd to not reveal weak DES keys, and the
    # maximum valid value is (2**24 - 1) which is odd anyway.
    $count = (1 << $count_log2) - 1;

    $output = '_';
    $output .= $this->itoa64[$count & 0x3f];
    $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 6) & 0x3f];
    $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 12) & 0x3f];
    $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 18) & 0x3f];

    $output .= $this->encode64($input, 3);

    return $output;
}

function gensalt_blowfish($input)
{
    # This one needs to use a different order of characters and a
    # different encoding scheme from the one in encode64() above.
    # We care because the last character in our encoded string will
    # only represent 2 bits.  While two known implementations of
    # bcrypt will happily accept and correct a salt string which
    # has the 4 unused bits set to non-zero, we do not want to take
    # chances and we also do not want to waste an additional byte
    # of entropy.
    $itoa64 = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    $output = '$2a$';
    $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->iteration_count_log2 / 10);
    $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->iteration_count_log2 % 10);
    $output .= '$';

    $i = 0;
    do {
        $c1 = ord($input[$i++]);
        $output .= $itoa64[$c1 >> 2];
        $c1 = ($c1 & 0x03) << 4;
        if ($i >= 16) {
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            break;
        }

        $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
        $c1 |= $c2 >> 4;
        $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
        $c1 = ($c2 & 0x0f) << 2;

        $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
        $c1 |= $c2 >> 6;
        $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
        $output .= $itoa64[$c2 & 0x3f];
    } while (1);

    return $output;
}

function HashPassword($password)
{
    $random = '';

    if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1 && !$this->portable_hashes) {
        $random = $this->get_random_bytes(16);
        $hash =
            crypt($password, $this->gensalt_blowfish($random));
        if (strlen($hash) == 60)
            return $hash;
    }

    if (CRYPT_EXT_DES == 1 && !$this->portable_hashes) {
        if (strlen($random) < 3)
            $random = $this->get_random_bytes(3);
        $hash =
            crypt($password, $this->gensalt_extended($random));
        if (strlen($hash) == 20)
            return $hash;
    }

    if (strlen($random) < 6)
        $random = $this->get_random_bytes(6);
    $hash =
        $this->crypt_private($password,
        $this->gensalt_private($random));
    if (strlen($hash) == 34)
        return $hash;

    # Returning '*' on error is safe here, but would _not_ be safe
    # in a crypt(3)-like function used _both_ for generating new
    # hashes and for validating passwords against existing hashes.
    return '*';
}

function CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash)
{
    $hash = $this->crypt_private($password, $stored_hash);
    if ($hash[0] == '*')
        $hash = crypt($password, $stored_hash);

    return $hash == $stored_hash;
}
```

}

I would be interested to use the same encryption mode for a C# using application to the same users when logging in. Can someone help me with a transformation from PHP in C#?

Comment: happy to help - what have done so far?  please show us your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new user registration part:

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(@"server=xx.xx.xx.xx;user id=user;password=password;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=website;sslmode=None;");
        string query = "Select * from users Where username= '" + tbUser.Text + "'";
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dtbl);
        if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username exist!");
        }
        else
        {
            if(tbUser.Text == "" | tbPass.Text == ""){
                MessageBox.Show("Fill in properly !");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string commString = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, permissions, homedir) VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4)";
                    string constring = @"server=xx.xx.xx.xx;user id=user;password=password;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=website;sslmode=None;";
                    string savedPasswordHash = CryptSharp.Crypter.Phpass.Crypt(tbPass.Text, salt);
                    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
                    {
                        using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand())
                        {
                            comm.Connection = conn;
                            comm.CommandText = commString;
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", tbUser.Text);
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", savedPasswordHash);
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", "rwu");
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", "/var/www/repository/HOME");
                            conn.Open();
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Register OK!");
                    tbPass.Text = null;
                    sqlcon.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Eroare. Contact admin!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the LOGIN part:

```
string userLogat = tbUser.Text;
            MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(@"server=xx.xx.xx.xx;user id=user;password=password;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=website;sslmode=None;");
            string query = "Select * from users Where username= '" + tbUser.Text + "'";
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dtbl);
            if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                string savedPasswordHash = dtbl.Rows[0][3].ToString();

                if (ValidatePassword(tbPass.Text, savedPasswordHash, salt))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Wellcome {tbUser.Text} !");
                    FormMain openMain = new FormMain(userLogat);
                    openMain.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Password for  {userLogat} error.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Username error!");
            }
            sqlcon.Close();
```

Generation salt do it at first by:

```
string salt = CryptSharp.Crypter.Phpass.GenerateSalt(8);
```

Checking your password by:

```
public static bool ValidatePassword(string pass, string passCriptat, string salt)
    {
        string CryptedInput = CryptSharp.Crypter.Phpass.Crypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass), salt);
        string CryptedPassword = CryptSharp.Crypter.Phpass.Crypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passCriptat), salt);
        return string.Equals(CryptedInput, CryptedPassword);
    }
```

Comment: With the password generated in C# (new registration) on the site in PHP goes to login, the C# application does not work. Am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, we succeeded. Here is the solution:
LOGIN button:

```
        string userLogat = tbUser.Text;
        MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(@"server=xx.xx.xx.xx;user id=user;password=password;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=website;sslmode=None;");
        string query = "Select * from users Where username= '" + tbUser.Text + "'";
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dtbl);
        if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            string savedPasswordHash = dtbl.Rows[0][3].ToString();
            if (CryptSharp.Crypter.CheckPassword(tbPass.Text, savedPasswordHash))
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Wellcome {tbUser.Text} !");
                FormMain openMain = new FormMain(userLogat);
                openMain.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Parola pentru userul {userLogat} nu exista valida.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Username incorect!");
        }
        sqlcon.Close();
```

The registration part is:

```
        MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(@"server=xx.xx.xx.xx;user id=user;password=password;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=website;sslmode=None;");
        string query = "Select * from users Where username= '" + tbUser.Text + "'";
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dtbl);
        if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username exista!");
        }
        else
        {
            if(tbUser.Text == "" | tbPass.Text == ""){
                MessageBox.Show("Completati campurile corespunzator !");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string commString = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, permissions, homedir) VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4)";
                    string constring = @"server=xx.xx.xx.xx;user id=user;password=password;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=website;sslmode=None;";
                    string savedPasswordHash = CryptSharp.Crypter.Phpass.Crypt(tbPass.Text, salt);

                    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
                    {
                        using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand())
                        {
                            comm.Connection = conn;
                            comm.CommandText = commString;
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", tbUser.Text);
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", savedPasswordHash);
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", "rwu");
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", "/var/www/repository/HOME");
                            conn.Open();
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Inregistrare reusita!");
                    tbPass.Text = null;
                    sqlcon.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Eroare la inregistrare. Contactati administratorul !");
                }
            }
        }
```

Before initialization I put the salt:

```
string salt = CryptSharp.Crypter.Phpass.GenerateSalt(8);
```